# Python/Flask - suddenly getting "ImportError: No module named..." error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm running into what I believe is a fairly common problem in Python apps - `ImportError: No module named lib.handle_data` - but I'm not experienced enough with the Python/Flask ecosystem to really understand why this is happening, especially since my code *was* working until I made a small adjustment and reinstalled some dependencies. Ok here's how it went down...

I'm working on a Flask app and, up until a little while ago, it was running fine. I realized that I hadn't included semantic versioning for the dependencies in my `setup.py` file. Originally, the file looked like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_app',
    packages=['my_app'],
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires='>3.6.4',
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
        'gtfs-realtime-bindings',
        'gunicorn',
    ],
)
```

which I changed to look like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_app',
    packages=['my_app'],
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires='>3.6.4',
    install_requires=[
        'flask==0.12.2',
        'gtfs-realtime-bindings==0.0.5',
        'gunicorn==19.7.1',
    ],
)
```

and then just to make sure all was well, I ran `python setup.py install` and everything seemed to go ok - none of the versions changed, as these were what had already been installed.

However, when I ran `flask run`, the server wouldn't start and I was left with the error:

```
import my_app.lib.handle_data as HandleData
ImportError: No module named lib.handle_data
```

and trying to start the server with gunicorn via

```
gunicorn my_app.my_app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

yields the same error (no surprise, I'm sure, just being comprehensive).

Here's the file structure:

```
setup.py
my_app/
   |
   - __pycache__/
   - __init__.py
   - my_app.py
   - lib/
      |
      - __pycache__/
      - __init__.py
      - handle_data.py
      - request.py
```

The contents of `my_app/__init__.py` are:

```
from .my_app import app
```

and `my_app/lib/__init__.py` is empty.

How did I break my app, and how can I fix this?

Python version is 3.6.4, running this on macOS Mojave, 10.14. And if I didn't make this clear, my app was running just fine before I made this change/reinstalled deps.

Comment: Not sure why it worked before, but you should probably add `"my_app.lib"` to `packages`.

Comment: @a_guest Huh! Yes, that fixed it! If you'd please submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `"my_app.lib"` to `packages` because otherwise the corresponding sub-package and the `my_app.lib.*` modules won't be installed. You can check the existing installation by

```
>>> import my_app
>>> my_app.__file__
'/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_app/__init__.py'
```

Now inspecting the corresponding directory will reveal that `lib` is missing. If you add `"my_app.lib"` to `packages` then the `lib` directory (package) will be installed as well.

As to why it worked before while you didn't change anything about the package setup / structure I can only speculate. There is however one thing about the installation process itself that can have an effect. If you had installed the package in `--editable` (`-e`) mode (or `python setup.py develop`)<sup>1</sup> before then your environment would contain a `my-app.egg-link` pointing to the package's source directory instead of a copy of the relevant files. This way the `my_app.lib` is of course not missing (as it's contained in the source directory). According to your description you did a "normal" installation after applying the changes and this requires the full structure as specified in `packages` to be complete (also using `--upgrade` would remove the link).

---

<sub>1. `--editable / -e` is the `pip` option to place a link to the source directory rather than to copy the relevant files; using `setup.py` directly the corresponding mode is `develop`, i.e. `python setup.py develop`.</sub>